# npx create-react-app command returns error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

So i decided to learn react following a tutorial. According to the tutorial I typed:

```
npm install -g create-react-app@1.5.2
```

Then I typed:

```
create-react-app my-app
```

After running this I typed:

```
npm start
```

It threw some error (I can't remember exactly what the error was. But it was something like package.json didn't include `npm start`, also it didn't include any template)
After a quick google search I found that the previous process was not recommended anymore.
According to the guide found [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#npm-start-or-yarn-start)

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package
> using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always
> uses the latest version.

So I typed `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` in cmd. After uninstalling I closed cmd and deleted the folder which was created created after running `npm install -g create-react-app`

Then after typing `npx create-react-app my-app` in cmd. But it returns this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "Amin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4996" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Farhan Bin Amin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-24T04_44_56_925Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

The debug log is included below:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'create-react-app@latest',
1 verbose cli   '--global',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Farhan',
1 verbose cli   'Bin',
1 verbose cli   'Amin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\4996',
1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
1 verbose cli   'error',
1 verbose cli   '--json'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose npm-session 0eec5b00126c667b
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for file:Amin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4996 Could not install from "Amin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4996" as it does not contain a package.json file.
8 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/Bin 124ms
9 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 178ms (from cache)
10 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/Bin 39ms
11 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for Bin@latest 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Bin - Not found
12 silly pacote tag manifest for create-react-app@latest fetched in 193ms
13 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
14 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 201ms
15 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\react\Amin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4996\package.json'
16 verbose cwd F:\react
17 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
18 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-react-app@latest" "--global" "--prefix" "C:\\Users\\Farhan" "Bin" "Amin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\4996" "--loglevel" "error" "--json"
19 verbose node v12.16.3
20 verbose npm  v6.14.4
21 error code ENOLOCAL
22 error Could not install from "Amin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4996" as it does not contain a package.json file.
23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I googled for hours but nothing seems to fix this problem.

**UPDATE:**
So it seems that only `yarn create react-app my-app` is working. But npm/npx are not. Thanks to @prisar for mentioning to try different method.

Comment: If you see my problem, you will see that I followed the official doc and still the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

try using `npm` or `yarn` instead. there seems to be some problem with npx cache. Once, try to clear the cache also.

Comment: So I tried to to use npm which didn't seem to work. But then used yarn but in cmd it said like I didn't had permission. So I opened power shell with admin privilege and then typed `yarn create react-app my-app` which is working. But still don't get why npm/npx aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best reference is the official guide which suggest,

> You’ll need to have Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine

So after ensuring the requirement, try to uninstall the global create-react-app and run npx instead.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

I think the tutorial is using the old of installing CRA, I might be wrong.

Comment: I have node `12.16.3` and npm `6.14.4` installed. Not sure what's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I too have that problem earlier. Try to delete node_modules, package-lock.json files from the root folder and run

> npm cache clean --force && npm install

and then-

> npx create-react-app my-app